# How can I consistently launch the rocket?

Tags: hearthstone

The Goblins vs. Gnomes board in Hearthstone features a spiff-tastic rocket in the upper-left quadrant.

Once, while playing with the beam-zapper in the bottom-right quadrant, I positioned it just right, and the beam hit the satellite, powered the rocket, and sent it blasting off the board.

The problem? I haven't been able to reproduce it since!

What's the secret there? How do I align the beam-zapper and send the rocket into the stratosphere?

[image]

Comment: If I hit the little blue square (or in that vicinity) my rocket always launches. Not sure why yours wouldnt. I do wish the rocket would come back so I could launch it again

Comment: I aimed the laser at the radio tower to the right of the rocket, and it launched for me. I've only tried this once, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must hit the blue energy tank below the satellite to launch the rocket. Usually, from the point where you start, 1 long and 1 short click on the button to move the laser left do the trick. If you miss, adjust your angle by clicking the buttons for left or right accordingly and remember there's a long and a short click.

Answer (score 2):

Try two short clicks on "left arrow". Always works for me